# 'animation' package in R saves GIF with status 127

Tags: r, gganimate

I am trying to use 'animate' package of R 3.1.3 in RStudio 0.98.1102 in a Windows 7 computer. I have already installed ImageMagick and if I write the following lines, I get an animated gif file.

```
library(animation)
ani.options('C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.4-Q16/convert.exe')
png(file="example%02d.png",width=200, height=200)
for(i in c(10:1,"GO!")){
    plot.new()
    text(.5,.5,i,cex=6)
}
dev.off()
system("magick -delay 80 *.png example_1.gif")
```

So far so good. But I face problems when I try to use gganimate package. I have just copied the following lines from the github page of animation package:

```
library(gapminder)
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
p <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, color = 
continent, frame = year)) +
geom_point() +
scale_x_log10() 
library(gganimate)
gganimate(p)
```

After the last line is executed, I get the following error:

[error message 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ1nz.png)

Now, I write the following command and run again to get a similar error message and no gif file is produced:

```
ani.options(convert = shQuote('C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.4-
Q16/magick.exe'))
gganimate(p)
```

Now if I write the lines below, I get error message but an animated gif file is produced.

```
ani.options(convert = shQuote('C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.4-
Q16/magick.exe'))
gganimate(p, "output.gif")
```

[error message 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCFor.png)

The animation is not shown in RStudio, I had to find the location of the working directory where the new gif file is saved.

I don't understand why is this happening and how to use gganimate() to generate .gif (inside RStudio) without any error message being generated. I will highly appreciate your feedback, suggestions, solutions to the above mentioned issues.

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me.  Did you install ImageMagick? It's needed for `gganimate` See here for instructions: https://rpubs.com/sjackman/gapminder-gganimate

Comment: Yes, I have installed ImageMagick and that works. I have already used system("magick -delay 80 *.png example_1.gif") to generate a gif file.